# Only allow touch after a certain time

Tags: swift, xcode, uitouch

For the game I am creating, I have a little animation of sorts at the beginning when the start button is pressed. However being able to touch the screen interferes with this animation. Is there any way I can have the user not be able to interact with the screen until (lets say 10 seconds) after the start button is clicked? Here is my code for the current users touch:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   
    for touch in touches {
        
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        player.position.x = location.x
        player.position.y = -300//location.y
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-isuserinteractionenabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable user interaction while clicking on the screen and enable it after 10 second as-

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   
    for touch in touches {
        
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        player.position.x = location.x
        player.position.y = -300//location.y
        
    }
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
         self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } 
}
```

If you want to disable user interaction for 10 seconds after clicking the start button for the first time, then **copy this code**

```
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
      self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

and **paste** it inside your Start button action function.

Comment: So i'm not quite sure what the problem is here. I inserted this code, however the first time you touch you can move everything as normal (which I already don't want), but when you touch it again, it will lock you out from touching the screen forever after that.

Comment: @mrman, got it and updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you!, can't believe I did not think of that. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

**Stop ClickEvent** in entire screen.

```swift
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

**Continue ClickEvent** after some time, *i.e.: 10 Sec.*

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) { 
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true 
}
```